# Locate from where Visual Studio 2015 debugger is reading symbol defs when source is not available

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015

I want to see from where a function definition is being read from in a project because it is neither where I expect it to be nor where "Go To Definition" in VS2015 claims it is.

I have an application calling a static library which calls a second static library all included as a solution in Visual Studio and both library included as project dependencies for the application. When I go to any call from the first library to a function defined in the second in the code and right-click->"Go To Definition" it takes me to the correct location in the second library.

However it definitely *not* getting the functions from that source when it runs, since it is returning the wrong answers and not giving the console output I added for debugging this problem. Another (toy) application that I wrote to check the code and is in a different solution also containing the libraries takes the definitions correctly.

If, while debugging, I click on these functions, I am told that the source is not available. Obviously it is reading the definitions from somewhere and I can look at the disassembly. After looking at the properties of all the projects, and searching for other versions of the second library on my computer, I still have no idea from where it might be getting different definitions. So it would be useful to know from where the debugger/compiler is reading in the compiled code from which it can generate the disassembly (and do the function).

The last line of code that is being executed from where I expect is:

```
dgstrf(opPt, column_permuted, relax, panel_size, etree, NULL, 0, col_perm_pt, row_perm_pt, lower, upper, glu, stats, status);
```

which according to "Go To Definition" should call a function that begins:

```
void
dgstrf (superlu_options_t *options, SuperMatrix *A,
    int relax, int panel_size, int *etree, void *work, int lwork,
    int *perm_c, int *perm_r, SuperMatrix *L, SuperMatrix *U,
    GlobalLU_t *Glu, /* persistent to facilitate multiple factorizations */
    SuperLUStat_t *stat, int *info)
{
    printf("doing dgstrf\n");
 ...
```

which after a while calls:

```
*info = dLUMemInit(fact, work, lwork, m, n, Astore->nnz,
                   panel_size, fill_ratio, L, U, Glu, &iwork, &dwork);
```

which starts:

```
int
 dLUMemInit(fact_t fact, void *work, int lwork, int m, int n, int annz,
      int panel_size, double fill_ratio, SuperMatrix *L, SuperMatrix *U,
          GlobalLU_t *Glu, int **iwork, double **dwork)
{
   printf("doing dLUMemInit\n");...
```

which calls in turn dLUWorkInit -> intCalloc, and then in the version that running in the real app (but not in the toy app that works) ->superlu_abort_and_exit -> fprintf

fprintf (in stdio.h) is the first thing since my wrapper function to dgstrf for which the call stack says it has source code.

It throws an exception "Access violation writing to location 0x0000000000000024." on the lines

```
__crt_va_start(_ArgList, _Format);
_Result = _vfprintf_l(_Stream, _Format, NULL, _ArgList);
__crt_va_end(_ArgList);
return _Result;
```

I've been through what *should* be the source code up to here and filled it with break points. They aren't hit and none of the console output I have set it to produce is.

Comment: Did you try the step-into option? using F-11 you could trace it. And you could put break points every where to see when and where it hits

Comment: Yeah, I tried it. The debugger is not seeing that code at all, so even one "step-into" flies straight past everything (and it's throwing an exception somewhere in there)

Comment: post that line of code where it doesn't step into it and the code behind where somewhere it throws an error

Comment: @FirstStep I've done that now. Hope it is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my particular case I was able to find out where the alternative definitions come from by asking colleagues if they could think of any other dependencies that might have been interfering. Not the most satisfying solution but it will do.